# How to override the default search block and make a button with Font Awesome?

Tags: theming, search

I want to override the default search block of Drupal and create a button like the image below:

[image]

However, I do not know how to do it. I have tried using **hook_form_alter** as well but it is not working:

```
function hook_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = html_entity_decode('&#xf002;');
  $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-button';
}
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to make these changes. I am still quite new to Drupal so I'm a bit lost and confused about these types of things. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried it with just CSS already?

Comment: Yes I have tried but the FontAwesome icon is not even appearing. I have added the reference for FontAwesome as well, but the CSS still does not seem to work as required.

Answer (score 1):

why not Learn how to make a custom block

as the search form only post to "/search/node?keys=SEARCHTERM"
so this will be easy to do:

lets first point you in the direction of making a block 
read - https://www.webwash.net/programmatically-create-block-drupal-8/ or google "drupal 8 create block programmatically"

or if you have Drupal console (https://drupalconsole.com/) installed you can just run

"drupal generate:plugin:block"

Now lets also learn how to make a custom twig template file to use in your block

see [Block not showing input fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/286823/block-not-showing-input-fields)

here showing the basic structure of the module

```
mymodule (dir)
 - mymodule.module
 - mymodue.info.yml
 - templates (dir) 
 -- mymodule-my-search-form.html.twig
 - src (dir)
 -- Plugin (dir)
 --- Block (dir) 
 --- MySerchForm.php 
(aka mymodule/src/Plugin/Block/MySerchForm.php)
```

in your blocks (mymodule/src/Plugin/Block/MySerchForm.php) build method:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function build() {
   $build = [];
   $build['my_search_form'] = [
     '#theme' => 'my_custom_search_form',
   ];
   return $build;
}
```

then in your module file (mymodule/mymodule.module)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'my_custom_search_form' => [
      'variables' => [],
      'template' => 'mymodule-my-search-form'
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then in your template file (templates/mymodule-my-search-form.html.twig)

```
<form action="/search/node" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="keys">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

then style the heck out of it ... 
aka google "how to add css in drupal 8 module how to add css in module"

hint, add a file  "mymodule.libraries.yml" (mymodule/mymodule.libraries.yml)
add a css file (mymodule/css/mymodule.css)

in mymodule.libraries.yml

```
mymodule-search-form:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/mymodule.css: {}
```

then in your block

```
$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mymodule-search-form';
```

clear cache lots

with all the above should put you on the right path figuring out a heck of alot more then just changing a search block :)

Comment: Nice answer but a little bit overhead maybe. All what OP wants is an icon on an existing button.