# Block not showing input fields

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a block as part of my custom module, I was it to show 2 text boxes (Input & Output) and have a generate button. I cant get it to show the input boxes! It seems they are being stripped out for some reason? I have tried with and without twig but my example below is without twig to keep it simple:

```
    <?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Block\GenerateBlock.
 */

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'generateblock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "generate_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Generate Code"),
 *   category = @Translation("mymodule")
 * )
 */
class generateblock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    // $twig = \Drupal::service('twig');
    // $template = $twig->loadTemplate(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates/generatecode.html.twig');
    // $output = $template->render([]);
    $output='<div id="GenerateCodeBox" class="featured-boxes featured-boxes-style-8">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="featured-box featured-box-primary featured-box-text-left" style="height: 301px;">
    <div class="box-content">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <h2>Generate <strong>Access Code</strong></h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="align-right">
    <h2><i class="fa fa-twitter">‌</i></h2>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group"> 
    <input class="form-control" id="codeToCheck" placeholder="Enter Input" type="text" value="" /> <span class="input-group-btn" id="generateMe"><button class="btn btn-default mr-xs mb-sm" type="button">Set</button>
    </span>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group"><input class="form-control" id="validationCode" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" /> <span class="input-group-btn" id="copyCode"><button class="btn btn-default mr-xs mb-sm" type="button">Copy</button></span></div>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mr-xs mb-lg" href="#" type="button">Learn More</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>';

    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $output,
    );
  }

}
```

I do not know why the inputs are being stripped out? What am i missing

**** Update ****

I have changed my code to the following and it is no longer stripping out the input boxes but it feels a bit "hacky" Do I need to specify a different render type or something:

```
class AccessCode extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $twig = \Drupal::service('twig');
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates/accesscode.html.twig');
    $output = $template->render([]);

    return array(
      '#markup' => $output,
      '#allowed_tags' => ['input','span','div','a','button','h2','strong','i',], 
    );
  }
```

Comment: The best way i think is to create a twig template and place into it you html take a look how to do it https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206290/twig-template-for-a-custom-block-plugin

Comment: You're right that what you're doing is a bit hacky, but it's better than your first attempt. Is there a reason you're not using Drupal's Form API to generate this form?  https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api

Answer (score 1):

try to follow best practises:
as no need to render anything on your get the twig template as drupal core handles this.

module structure:

mymodule

- mymodule.module
- mymodule.info.yml
- mymodule.libraries.yml
- templates (dir)
  -- templates/accesscode.html.twig
- src (dir) 
  -- src/Plugin/Block
  ----- AccessCode.php

in mymodule.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return [
      'accesscode_block' => [
        'variables' => [
          'test' => null,
         ],
         'template' => 'accesscode', 
//no need for full accesscode.html.twig as drupal knows. 
      ],
    ];
}
```

then in your src/Plugin/Block/  AccessCode.php

```
 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function build() {
  $build = [];
  $build['my-block'] = [
      '#theme' => 'accesscode_block',
      '#test' => 1234,
  ];
  // Attach js or css easier. 
  $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mymodule-accesscode';

// Could even add a form element like ..
 $build['some_field'] = [
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => 'My Field:',
 ];
  return $build;
}
```

then in your accesscode.html.twig you can use the twig var {{test}}